# how to turn off "setval" output when import psql dump

Tags: postgresql, psql

I already tried both:

```
SET client_min_messages TO WARNING;
```

And the `-q` option when I ran:

```
psql -q -U postgres -d myDB -f /Users/hoaphan/dev/postgres_dump -p 5432
```

However its output(pages like this):

```
 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

 setval
--------
      1
(1 row)

...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The "quiet" option `-q` is defined as: "*run quietly (no messages, **only query output**)*".

The result of `setval()` is a  query result, not a message, so the quiet option doesn't suppress this.

If you don't want to see query results, you can redirect their output to `/dev/null` using the `-o` switch:

```
psql -o /dev/null -q -U postgres -d myDB -f /Users/hoaphan/dev/postgres_dump -p 5432
```

<sup>(I can't test it on Linux right now, but the equivalent thing works on Windows)</sup>

Comment: I thought 'bout this, too. But this this would mean I wouldn't see ERROR if there is either, right? Unless I open that file.
Thing is I don't want those ouput because they'r not informative at all, and with my dump file, I have like a lot of scrolling to get through that part. Though I would still like to see ERROR if there is any.

Comment: @HoaPhan: you will still see error messages. It's only the output of `select` statements that is suppressed.

Comment: Ouch... I just re-checked so they come from select statement in the dump files... I didn't notice there were "select..." inside, not sure what they do...:
SELECT pg_catalog.setval('"<tableName>"', 1, false);

Comment: @HoaPhan: that's the output you are seeing: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

Comment: The Windows equivalent of `/dev/null` is `NUL`, I believe. No extension, no path, just those 3 letters. You're actually not allowed to create a file by that name, so instead of `-o` you may have to use output redirect with `>`

Comment: @coladict: I did test it with `-o nul` on Windows and it worked, but I didn't have a Linux with `psql` around to check it. If you redirect the output then HoaPhan would indeed see no errors I think. Just redirecting the _query_ output should be fine when restoring a dump

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can turn it off without modifiying the dump file, or piping it to a custom filtering command, as that will mean turn off query output, but if you don't need any of the it, just use -o switch to redirect it to the file you like or /dev/null.